# OpenCV function to compute product of array elements that is similar to MATLAB's prod?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I want to compute products along each dimension of an OpenCV `Mat` in C++. Apart from looping through each row or column of the `Mat`, is there any existing function that already takes care of this? An equivalent to Matlab's `prod()` function is essentially what I want.

Comment: It might help if you briefly explain what matlab prod() does.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. prod() is a Matlab function that computes products along each dimension of a given matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such function in OpenCV. The closest to your needs is `reduce()`, which does different operations per row/coloumn, but it only can extract sum, mean, min or max. Not product. So, that's it, you should write your own function.

Or better expand the [`cv::reduce()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sum#void%20reduce%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20dim,%20int%20rtype,%20int%20dtype%29) function, and send the patch to [code.opencv.org](http://code.opencv.org) Wouldn't it be great?

Comment: Thank you. cv::reduce() is indeed pretty close to what I want, and expand it is a great idea!